# Why am I getting the Forbidden -The resource you have requested .. message for Single Sign On?

Tags: single-sign-on, ibm-cloud

In my trial account, in US South, I created a Single Sign On service and bound it to an application and now am trying to go back into it and I got this page-

Forbidden

The resource you have requested is secured by Access Manager WebSEAL.

Explanation

There are two possible reasons why this message appeared:

```
You are not logged in to this secure domain.
You are logged in to this secure domain, but do not have the correct permissions to access the resource.
```

Solutions

You have an account for this secure domain but need to log in: You must first access this resource via HTTPS (SSL) and login to the secure domain. Re-access the page using HTTPS.

You do not have an account with this secure domain: Please contact your Account Administrator to obtain login and password information.

You are logged in but still denied access to the page: If you continue to get this message, you probably do not have the correct permissions to access the resource. Please contact your Security Administrator for assistance.

This happened yesterday afternoon too.

I was able to click on the Single Sign On service earlier today and update the Logout url and now I'm getting this message.

I tried stopping the app and then restarting and still can't get in.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is an odd case. The error message indicates there is problem with your account. You were not authenticated successfully to the secure domain. I see another similar case in which the person's account does not have user's name in it. So you might want to check your account profile to see if any required
information like family name, given name, etc is missing.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried now and am able to get into the Single Sign On service I have bound to my app, so not sure what was wrong the other day.  I did not make any changes to my account either.
Thanks for the response though.